# Vector Product of complex vectors

Tags: vectors, orthogonality, cross-product

I need to get a vector orthogonal to $\mathbf{A}=(1,i,1,-i)$ and $\mathbf{B}=(i,1,i,-1)$ where $i^2=\sqrt{-1}$.  Note also that $\mathbf{A}.\mathbf{B}=0$.

I was thinking to take the cross product, but not sure if this is possible/appropriate for vectors of length 4.  Would appreciate any advice/comments.

Comment: In a general case you can start with any vector that is not linearly dependent with the two first ones, and you can produce a new orthogonal with Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: I created $\mathbf{C}=(1,1,i,i)$ and did Gram-Scmidt on the three vectors.  But when I tested orthogonality of the results, I got orthogonal vectors for two pairs, $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{c}$, but the dot product of $\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$ was non-zero.

Comment: Then you made it mistake in the algorithms. If I had to guess, probably related to complex conjugation. You have to be careful which vectors to conjugate during the Gram-Schmidt algorithm. Gram-Schmidt should work for arbitrary dimensions just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the set of all vectors orthogonal to $A$ and $B$ by setting up the linear system of two equation in four unknowns $X = [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4] $ as follows

$ \begin{bmatrix} A^T \\ B^T \end{bmatrix} {X^*} = 0 $

Solving, you get

$ X = (-t, s,t, s) $ , $t,s \in \mathbb{R} $

Verify

$A \cdot X = (-t) + i s + t - i s = 0 $

$B \cdot X = -i t + s + i t - s = 0 $